# How to configure spdlog logger used in a pybind11 module

Tags: python, c++, logging, pybind11, spdlog

I'm using spdlog in various C++ libraries for which Python bindings are created with pybind11.

Now I'm wondering if there is a nice way how I can configure these loggers (mostly the level and format) from the Python side.

Currently I am creating a separate logger for each class in the constructor (`logger_` is a class member):

```cpp
MyClass::MyClass()
{
    logger_ = spdlog::get(LOGGER_NAME);
    if (!logger_)
    {
        logger_ = spdlog::stderr_color_mt(LOGGER_NAME);
    }
    logger_->debug("Logger is set up");
}
```

Now I can just use MyClass and it will create and use a logger with default settings.  If I want to change this, I can do so by creating a logger with the proper name before creating the class:

```cpp
auto logger = spdlog::stdout_color_st(MyClass::LOGGER_NAME);
logger->set_level(spdlog::level::debug);
logger->set_pattern("[%l] %n: %v");

MyClass c;
```

However, I can't find a good way to do this when using the Python bindings of `MyClass`.  I saw that there is already a Python package binding spdlog, so I tried the following:

```py
import spdlog
logger = spdlog.ConsoleLogger(MyClass.LOGGER_NAME)
logger.set_level(spdlog.LogLevel.DEBUG)
logger.set_pattern("[%l] %n: %v")

c = MyClass()
```

However, this does not affect the logger used inside `MyClass` (I assume there is simply no connection between the spdlog instance from the Python package and the one in my C++ code).

So long story short:  Is there a way how I can configure the logger used in the C++ code from the Python side?
If there is a way without having to manually pass a logger to the constructor of each class, that would be great.  But I'm not sure if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jwm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76410571/2095383) pointed me to a working solution.  The logger can be created on the Python side and be registered with the module containing the C++ class by also binding `spdlog::register_logger()` in that module.

1. Add a binding for `spdlog::register_logger()` in the module that binds `MyClass`.  So the code for binding looks like this:

   ```
   PYBIND11_MODULE(mylib, m)
   {
       pybind11::class_<MyClass>(m, "MyClass")
           /* ... */;

       m.def("register_logger", &spdlog::register_logger);
   }
   ```
2. In the Python code, use that binding to register the logger with the C++ module:

   ```py
   import spdlog
   import mylib

   logger = spdlog.ConsoleLogger(mylib.MyClass.LOGGER_NAME)
   logger.set_level(spdlog.LogLevel.DEBUG)
   logger.set_pattern("[%l] %n: %v")
   # register logger with the function from mylib, so it is accessible inside MyClass
   mylib.register_logger(logger.get_underlying_logger())

   c = mylib.MyClass()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the python binding extensively, but see [the documentation](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/wiki/2.-Creating-loggers), particularly **Note 2**:

> Note 2: Manually created loggers (i.e. those you construct directly) do not get automatically registered and will not be found by the `get("...")` call.
>
> If you want to register such logger use the `register_logger(...)` function:
>
> ```cpp
> spdlog::register_logger(my_logger);
> ...
> auto the_same_logger = spdlog::get("mylogger");
> ```

Assuming `register_logger(...)` is exposed in the python binding, you need to register the logger you created so that your class can see it.

Comment: `register_logger` is not bound by the Python package but since I found the idea promising, I took the code and added the binding.  However, when calling it, it fails with an error, saying that a logger with that name already exists.  I double-checked in pure C++ and get the same error there, so it seems that note from the documentation is outdated.

Comment: I’m just starting with `spdlog` myself. I can tell you that `spdlog::get()` returns a `nullptr` if the name is unregistered; if `register_logger` says the name is already bound, then it is. Also, registration may not “flow” between DLLs. I think the correct pattern is to call `get` and if null, create then register

Comment: I checked with the maintainer, the note in the docs is still valid, there was some misunderstanding on my side what is meant by "manually created".  Anyway, the Python bindings already take care of the registration internally.

Comment: "Also, registration may not “flow” between DLLs."  -- I think this is the root of the problem. It seems that the registries used in my C++ code and in the Python package do not interact, so there may not be an easy solution to my problem.

Comment: Oh, I just got it wrong where I need to register.  Before I added bindings for `register_logger` to the spdlog Python package but there it is useless.  Instead, I need to add it to the module that binds my C++ class.  Maybe this is what you meant in the first place?  I wrote an answer describing what exactly I did.  However, I'm happy to accept your answer, if you clarify it a bit (feel free to use the code snippets from my answer, if you want).